# Converting line to set of H3 hexagons?

Tags: geometry-conversion, h3, dggs

What is a proper way to convert a GeoJSON linestring to a set of H3 hexagons?

I came up with an algorithm where I

1. extract points from a line,
2. calculate an H3 hexagon of these points `geo_to_h3`
3. connect the pairs of H3 hexagons `h3-line`
4. concatenate the pair paths removing duplicating hexagons

I wonder if there is a better way to do the conversion?

Comment: Hi, have you had any updates?

Comment: Hey! I found [alphabetasoup's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/431534/177045) suitable for my application (vessels routes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is fine, with two caveats:

- **You should preserve order** by using an ordered data structure (and not an unordered set).
- **You should allow for some repetitions** by using a data structure that allows for some repeated DGGS cells: this allows for the representation of self-intersecting lines. You can do this by eliminating only *sequential* duplicates (which are redundant, unless perhaps you wanted to record the original vertex density, which is possible).

I have [an implementation of this in Python](https://github.com/DahnJ/H3-Pandas/issues/11#issuecomment-1110321047):

```py
from typing import Iterator, Union

import h3
from shapely.geometry.linestring import LineString
from shapely.geometry.multilinestring import MultiLineString

def sequential_deduplication(func: Iterator[str]) -> Iterator[str]:
    '''
    Decorator that doesn't permit two consecutive items to be the same
    '''
    def inner(*args):
        iterable = func(*args)
        last = None
        while (cell := next(iterable, None)) is not None:
            if cell != last:
                yield cell
            last = cell
    return inner

@sequential_deduplication
def h3polyline(line: Union[LineString, MultiLineString], resolution: int) -> Iterator[str]:
    '''
    Iterator yeilding H3 cells representing a (multi)line,
    retaining order and self-intersections
    '''
    if line.geom_type == 'MultiLineString':
        # Recurse after getting component linestrings from the multiline
        for l in map(lambda geom: h3polyline(geom, resolution), line.geoms):
            yield from l
    else:
        coords = zip(line.coords, line.coords[1:])
        while (vertex_pair := next(coords, None)) is not None:
            i, j = vertex_pair
            a = h3.geo_to_h3(*i[::-1], resolution)
            b = h3.geo_to_h3(*j[::-1], resolution)
            yield from h3.h3_line(a, b) # inclusive of a and b
```

Although it accepts multilinestring input, it doesn't really retain the distinction of multiple parts (I just didn't need that distinction).

That said, you might not care about order or self-intersections. This really depends on the intended application of your H3-discretised representation of a line. For lines with really long distances between vertices, perhaps first projecting and densifying a line would be sensible.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem, similar solution. Only one additional step that seemed to provide a smoother / more accurate result (i.e., H3s that more closely follow the shape of the line).

For each set of points along the line, create a "sub-line", take the centerpoint of that sub-line, and run `h3-line` from start --> centerpoint and centerpoint --> end.

More detail for clarity:

1. Extract points from linestring
2. Calculate H3 for starting point
3. Calculate H3 for "next" point (point+1) -- note: make sure not to end up going back to the first point when you point+1 on the last point in the linestring
4. Create "line" between starting point and next point
5. Get centroid of line
6. Calculate H3 for centroid
7. Use `h3-line` for start-->mid & mid-->next
8. Concatenate / remove duplicate h3s

Comment: It feels like this solution is useful for lines with sparse points.

Answer (score 1):

I want to share a discussion from a [Github issue](https://github.com/uber/h3/issues/569). I think it is valuable regarding the question.

[Nick Rabinowitz](https://github.com/nrabinowitz) said

> Your approach is what I would have recommended. h3_line has some
> limitations here - it's describing a path between two cells, so it may
> not overlap perfectly with the line it's representing. The only
> guarantees it offers are 1) the path it returns is the shortest path
> (though there may be many shortest paths of equal length) and 2) each
> successive cell touches the previous cells but none of the cells in
> the line before that. The shortest path guarantee usually means that
> h3_line follows great arcs rather than cartesian lines, which may or
> may not be what you need.
>
> If you want to make sure that the line is covered by H3 cells, you
> might try e.g. sampling indexes along the length of the line,
> buffering them by 1, and then removing indexes that the line does not
> intersect. This is a much more expensive operation than h3_line, but
> it would ensure that the line is fully covered.

[Kevin Sahr](https://github.com/sahrk) added

> Just to clarify, within each icosahedron face the grid shortest path
> will follow a great circle arc, which maps to a cartesian line in the
> H3 projection. If you want to precisely capture a great circle
> arc/line that crosses icosahedron edges, you would need to break-up
> the original arc/line wherever it intersects an edge, and then perform
> your algorithm on each of the resulting line segments.